# Best TinyMce editor Image Manager / File upload for Asp.net Mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-2.0

What is the best Image Manager to integrate in TinyMce editor apart the official Moxiecode commercial ones?

I'm looking to integrate a light texteditor in an asp.net mvc application and I choosed the Tinymce solution (and not the classic FCKEditor as this seems more lightweight and more jquery friendly).

Sadly TinyMce doesn't come with the Image Manager or Document Manager integrated like FCKeditor but you must buy them as plugins form Moxiecode.

I've looked other plugins but till now I've not find any decend and light solution that works with asp.net mvc framework.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of open source plugins on SourceForge,

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=103281&atid=738747
(search for image)

The plugin architecture is easy to understand if you know Javascript.
If you have the time you could roll out your own.

Comment: For the life of me, I haven't found one yet. Has anyone had success?

Comment: But I didn't get the plugin from the site, which plugin you are used?

Answer (score 5):

Ajax File Manager http://filemanager.3ntar.net/
free and cooool

Comment: Link is not longer valid.

Answer (score 3):

This is an integration of TinyMCE with FCKEditor File Upload Manager in ASP.NET MVC 3, should give it a try: http://tinymcefckfilemanger.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

http://www.ilyax.com/imagebrowser/ free and best :)

Comment: where is the upload?

Answer (score 1):

You can try: http://tinymcefckfilemanger.codeplex.com/

However, you must have some customizes to make it work!

:)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best solution

http://www.andyarndt.net/TinyFileManager.aspx#sthash.4MgLV1Oi.dpbs

Comment: i know it's an old answer,but how did you customize it, i mean i need it to upload images and files for every user to his folder not to a general folder ,i mean all users then can get other users images,i need it to upload images to a private folder for every user

Answer (score 0):

Carlton : Alfresco seems to be a Java based solution.
Ta: I've looked into the plugin folders but none was really good for asp.net mvc.
What I'm now testing is a mix between Tiny with the image uploader of FCKEditor:
this is the pho version but I think it is pretty easy to convert to .net [Tinyfck][1]

[1]: this: http://p4a2.crealabsfoundation.org/tinyfck

Answer (score 0):

I just started a project on codeplex that integrates nicely with ASP.NET MVC 2. Let me know if anyone wants to help out... I'm looking to integrate cropping (via JCrop) and resizing soon.

http://aspnetadvimage.codeplex.com/

You can download the sample project on the "Source Code" tab.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for asp.net mvc 
http://aspnetadvimage.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Answer (score 0):

Old question. However, it would be helpful to someone.

http://www.andyarndt.net/TinyFileManager.aspx is a .net web application. Works fine with webforms as well. You can do bit customization to get it worked with MVC as well.

---

Edit:

You can refer to the sample application provided in [Github TinyFileManager.NET](https://github.com/arndta/TinyFileManager.NET) to how to configure and refer the documentation mentioned in above mentioned page.

Custom CSS to avoid some conflicts with Bootstrap ver. 3.x.x:

```
    div.mce-fullscreen
    {
        z-index: 1030;
    }
    div.mce-edit-area
    {
        border-width: 1px !important;
        border-left-width: 0 !important;
        border-bottom-width: 0 !important;
    }
    .mce-combobox .mce-btn
    {
        width: 44px !important;
        height: auto !important;
    }
    .mce-combobox .mce-btn button
    {
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
```

ASP.net Control:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAnnouncements" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" AutoComplete="off"
                CssClass="form-control elm1"></asp:TextBox>
```

TinyMCE Javascript:

```
    tfm_path = '/fileman';
    tinymce.init({
        //            document_base_url: "http://localhost:58841/",
        //            relative_urls: true,
        selector: "textarea.elm1",
        mode: "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector: "tinymce",
        theme: "modern",
        // width: 300,
        height: 300,
        plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
    "emoticons template paste textcolor "
],
        //    content_css: "css/content.css",
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | forecolor backcolor emoticons | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullscreen ",
        image_advtab: true,
        encoding: "xml",
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on("SaveContent", function (i) {
                i.content = i.content.replace(/&#39/g, "&apos");
            });
        }
    });
```

When saving the database, save directly, and when re-binding, to the textbox, use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`.

Comment: i know it's an old answer,but how did you customize it, i mean i need it to upload images and files for every user to his folder not to a general folder ,i mean all users then can get other users images,i need it to upload images to a private folder for every user