# how to use tinymce with images on my website like stackoverflow does

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, tinymce

i have tinymce embedded in my website, so if users want to edit content, then can click on an "EDIT" link and it brings up the content in tinymce editor.  when they click "Save", i save the html to a database.  this works perfect and avoids them calling me when they need content changes as they can go in directly and next time they reload the main page, it loads up their changed content.

they now want to be able to add their own images.  I see there is [some image support in tinymce as seen here](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/example_22.php), but in my case, the images would be on their computer.

So i am looking for some advice on how to handle image support using tinymce on my asp.net mvc website similar to how stackoverflow allows you to upload and include an image in your question all in one step

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and solved it by;

Allowing the user to upload images which i then stored in the file system.

Once the image was saved then you could use tinyMCE to link to it.

It's a round-about way of doing it but it worked.  If your images are stored on a users computer then you're going to need to implement something like this me thinks as you can't assume you can link to the image and if you can you can't be sure the computer will be on.

Comment: any recommendations for a plugin to allow image uploading, etc

Comment: you didn't mention a plugin so i think the down vote is a little harsh

Answer (score 5):

I guess you need to take a look here:

[Best TinyMce editor Image Manager / File upload for Asp.net Mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604/best-tinymce-editor-image-manager-file-upload-for-asp-net-mvc)

it has a list of tinyMCE file browsers/uploaders/managers which work with MVC :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give this TinyMCE-plugin a try (the official Moxiecode plugins are quite expensive):

http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/Tinymce-Ajax-File-Manager/

I haven't tested it yet, but it's a free add on that allows uploading and selecting files.

Comment: in PHP... the question is about MVC.

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 supports embedded images. You can embed image in html code as a base64 string.
Example Code:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQYmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw==" alt="Base64 encoded image" width="150" height="150"/>
```

There is a opensource TinyMCE plugin available in github:

https://github.com/buddyexpress/bdesk_photo