# TinyMce editor Image Uploader/Manager

Tags: image, file-upload, tinymce

I'm looking for TinyMCE Image Uploader/Manager.

I've read this topic

[Best TinyMce editor Image Manager / File upload for Asp.net Mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604/best-tinymce-editor-image-manager-file-upload-for-asp-net-mvc)

And I found there very nice plugin http://www.ilyax.com/imagebrowser

posted by Ilyax.

I've tested this plugin and the problem is - it is not working in IE 9.

Please if anyone knows about other plugin which works ok in most of browsers post links here.

And If somebody has any way to contact Ilyax please write down any info. Maybe he solved this IE9 problem already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like **MCImageManager** (http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/enterprise/mcimagemanager.php). I use it for my sites. Works for all browsers I've tested, including Firefox, Chome, and IE.

I tried a couple free plugins. Don't remember which ones exactly but they were all awful. Sometimes it's worth biting the bullet and saving time. [Note: I have absolutely no affiliation with the company that owns TinyMCE. Just have a couple personal pages.]

Comment: Well probably you are right but I think there must be some normal free plugin too :) I liked Ilyax plugin but his demo is not working in IE9 that's the problem :(