# TinyMCE editor Image Manager/Upload in Django

Tags: javascript, django, tinymce, image-uploading

I am using TinyMCE editor, and it is great. But I having problems with including images. I have been hunting for free image hosting, but that doesn't seem easy to come by. So I finally decided I will upload the image to my own space but for that also I need to write the proper script.

I have found solutions but that are for [Asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604/best-tinymce-editor-image-manager-file-upload-for-asp-net-mvc) and I am working in Django/Python. Can anybody guide me in how I can write the javascript that will add a browse button to the image popup, so that the user can can upload an image from his computer or provide a direct link to an online image.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You may try django-ckeditor. It's another JS editor, but much better for me and upload works "out of the box"

Comment: For the upload part, where are the files uploaded? Are they uploaded on our own server or does it use third party image hosting

Comment: On your server. https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor#installation. You only need to specify CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH

Comment: @DenisKabalkin Thanks alot, it definitively seems to be a better solution than using TinyMCE.

Comment: And I came to the same conclusion =)
So, i'll add my answer and you can approve it ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try django-ckeditor. It's another JS editor, but much better for me and upload works "out of the box"

Comment: I've spent 2 days trying to do this with TinyMCE and had it working in 30 minutes with django-ckeditor