# TinyMCE editor with file upload capability for ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce

I need to have Editor with file upload capability.[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604/best-tinymce-editor-image-manager-file-upload-for-asp-net-mvc) suggest some choices but none of them sounds appropriate.and [this one](http://aspnetadvimage.codeplex.com/) is for `Asp.net MVC2` while I'm working with `ASP.Net MVC4`.

Comment: guess you are looking for a free upload manager?

Comment: yes,of course integration of Editor and file uploader.Use should be able to create reach contents.

Comment: my question was aiming at the point if you are willing to pay for it or not (there is a good solution from the tinymce developers, but that costs money)

Comment: U mean there isn't a free solution?

Comment: well, there might be one, but i am not using it

Comment: What's wrong with TinyMCE combined with the image plugin? You could also try TinyMCE with Plupload.

Comment: Image plugin just asks for URL of image,It doesn't have options for uploading and using returned URL of uploaded Image.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use CKEditor, and CKfinder for file upload ? CKFinder is paid, but you could find few free alternatives for Ckfinder.

pdwfilebrowser is free, and works well with TinyMCE or Ckeditor. You could find more free upload plugins for both.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdwfilebrowser/